# Checking if a linear code exists - singleton , hamming and gilbert-varshamov bounds do not help.

Tags: combinatorics, cryptography, coding-theory

Suppose I want to check if a (11, 6, 4) code exists.

I cannot prove non-existence using the singleton and the hamming bound. I also cannot prove existence using the gilbert-varshamov bound. I'm not sure what is the best way to go then -  shall I just try to create a parity-check matrix?

Comment: For heaven's sake never use Singleton with binary non-trivial codes. That's a non-starter. But why did Hamming bound fail to prove non-existence? After all ${16\choose 3}>2^8$. Griesmer bound will also prove non-existence.

Comment: Sorry, wrong code... my bad. (11,6,4) is the one I was interested in.

Comment: Have you heard of a $(16,11,4)$ code? What happens, if you shorten it in five positions?

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen could you please explain.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried to simply create a parity check matrix for the code and it turned out to be quite easier than I thought.

Assuming $r = n - k = 5$

$$
H=\left(\begin{array}{l}
11100\\
01110\\
00111\\
10011\\
11001\\
11111\\
10000\\
01000\\
00100\\
00010\\
00001
\end{array}\right)
$$

Any 3 $(d-1)$ rows are linearly independent and there is at least one set of of 4 $(d)$ linearly dependent rows.

Comment: +1: A good choice for $H$. Parity of weights of the rows makes it plain that any three are linearly independent.

Comment: But why are you writing $H$ in that way? I am used to calling the transpose of that $H$. So my parity check equation reads like: $x$ is a codeword, iff $Hx^T=0$ (or $xH^T=0$). It sounds like your book is using it differently. The reason I'm used to doing it that way is one of layout. It is simpler to squeeze a matrix with many columns and only a few rows into a page than the other way around :-)

Comment: I see, I'm using "Coding theory and cryptography, the essentials" by Hankerson, Hoffman, Leonard, Lindner, Phelps, Rodger and Wall.

Answer (score 3):

An extended Hamming code has parameters $(16,11,4)$. By shortening it in five positions you get the desired $(11,6,4)$-code. The process can also be described as follows. Let $C$ be that $(16,11,4)$-code. Select a set of five bit positions. Let $C'$ be the subspace consisting of those words of $C$ that have a zero at all those five positions. This amounts to adding five extra parity checks, so $C'$ is a linear code. Because all the words of $C'$ are also words of $C$, its minimum weight is still $\ge4$. Because we place 5 extra parity checks, the dimension of $C'$ is at least $11-5=6$. Finally, if we throw away the five shared zeros of all the words of $C'$, we get a code of length $11$.

---

Equivalently you can just throw away any five columns from the parity check matrix 
$$
H=\left(\begin{array}{l}
1111 1111 1111 1111\\
0000 0000 1111 1111\\
0000 1111 0000 1111\\
0011 0011 0011 0011\\
0101 0101 0101 0101
\end{array}\right)
$$
of the $(16,11,4)$ extended Hamming code.

Comment: I understand the procedure but what I don't get is how you decide that the (16,11,4) code is the one that will do the job in the 1st place.

Comment: If you shorten an $(n,k,d)$-code $m$ times, you get an $(n-m,k-m,d)$-code. $16-5=11$, $11-5=6$. A little bit of experience reverse engineering such a step helps. It is actually a relatively common trick when playing with short codes.